# How to dynamically change the centre of a google maps without erasing markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Initially, my map would be pointing to the user's current location. I am giving an option where in he can choose a city from an auto complete box, once he selects the new location from auto complete, I will get a new (lat,lng) coordinates for which I would like to focus my map to.

From my knowledge of Maps API, I am able to think of it as changing the centre(however, the centre is set only while loading the map). I want to achieve this focus to user selected location on google maps. Can some one help me out. Thanks in advance. Using Google Maps js api v3.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can simply move the map with `map.setCenter(LatLng)`. This method will not use any other markers and will not erase existing markers. You could also move the map via the `panTo(LatLng)` function. Both methods are also available after the map has been initialized.

[Here is the documentation for these methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

Comment: `panTo()` is better than `setCenter` that it gives you an animation. It is useful, because customers won't have such headache as when using `setCenter`.

Comment: In angular-google-maps panTo() worked, setCenter() gave "setCenter is not a function" error. Seemingly it is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 15):

**jOnes** is right,  you need to use `setCenter()`

```
function initialize()
{
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('MapDiv');
    var map;
    var address = "Vilnius, Lithuania";
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // Get LatLng information by name
    geocoder.geocode({
        "address": address
        }, function(results, status){
                map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                // Center map (but check status of geocoder)
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            })
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example dude - setCenter worked; +1 for geocode example :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Geocoder is just a hint, in case you want to use it

Answer (score 5):

```js
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE));
```

or

```js
map.setCenter({lat: LATITUDE, lng: LONGITUDE});
```

This Return None Value

Comment: I am calling a function when a user clicks a button which will center the map on their location. when I try your method I get map.setCenter is not a function.