# How to dynamically change the centre of a google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var mapOptions = {
                   zoom: 14,
                   center: new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude,langitude),
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  };
```

dynamically change the centre of a google maps please any one tel

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change the centre of a google maps without erasing markers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554688/how-to-dynamically-change-the-centre-of-a-google-maps-without-erasing-markers) Follow this link.

Comment: any example code available

Answer (score 1):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    title: markerTitle,
    map: map,
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());//sets center with animation
    //map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); // sets center without animation
});
```

Comment: will you explain what you really want to achieve ?

Comment: i have use this code  map.setCenter({
                            lat : lattitude,
                            lng : langitude
                        });

Comment: button1<input type="button" value="some" id="somedata"/>  button2<input type="button" value="map" id="map"/>